# WPF StringCollection + TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, application-settings

ApplicationSetting: RenameSettings - System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection - User - *wall of text"

```
<Application x:Class="app.App"
         ...
         xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:app.Properties" 
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <properties:Settings x:Key="Settings" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>

<Window x:Class="app.MainWindow"
        ...
        xmlns:p="clr-namespace:app.Properties"
        Height="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.Height, Mode=TwoWay}" MinHeight="300"
        ...
        >

    <Window.Resources>
        <p:Settings x:Key="settings" />
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource settings}">
        <Menu ... ... />
        <Label ... />
        <TextBox Margin="12,129,12,12" Name="textBlock1"  
            Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.RenameSettings, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

StringCollection... I'd like to bind it to a TextBox, Text, for viewing/editing. Following a similar patterns I've seen here and there:

I've tried TextBox, TextBlock, Label (only shows the word "(Collection)")... How can I bind this elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot... Switched to ListBox ItemsSource...

```
    <ListBox Margin="12,129,12,12" Name="textBlock1"  
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Settings}, Path=Default.RenameSettings, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```